# Funcao MAP aplicada a apenas uma coluna

Tags: pandas, map

Estou tentando mapear o valor "Outros" a uma coluna "Carreira", segundo alguns criterios. Por exemplo, quando a coluna contiver o valor Lixeiro ou Ajudante, eu quero q esse valor seja substituido pelo valor Outros. O comando abaixo esta rodando sem erro:

```
aip['Carreira'] = aip['Carreira'].map({'Chefe de Limpeza': 'Outros', 'Lixeiro': 'Outros', 'Auxiliar de Limpeza': 'Outros', 'Ajudante': 'Outros', 'Carreira Externa': 'Outros' })
```

O problema e que, ao rodar esse comando, todas as outras colunas sao substituidas pelo valor NAN, ou seja, nao e so a coluna Carreira que esta sendo afetada, mas todas as outras. COmo sanar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi com ifs, aplicando uma funcao na coluna.

```
row = aip['Carreira']
def get_description(row):
    if row == 'Ajudante':
        return 'Outros'
    elif row == 'Auxiliar Geral':
        return 'Outros'
    elif row == 'Levantando de copos':
        return 'Outros'
    elif row == 'Motorista':
        return 'Outros'
    elif row == 'Presidente':
        return 'Outros'
    else:
        return row
aip['Carreira'] = aip['Carreira'].apply(get_description)
counts = aip['Carreira'].value_counts()
#explode = (0, 0, 0,0.4, 0)
counts.plot(kind='pie', labels = None, figsize=(11,8), legend=True, autopct='%.2f%%')
plt.show()
```